# ЧПУ с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Есть вот такие правила перенаправления:

```
RewriteRule index.html /index.php?act=main [QSA,L]
RewriteRule main/?$ /index.php?act=main [QSA,L]
RewriteRule search/?$ /index.php?act=search [QSA,L]
RewriteRule main/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=main [QSA,L]
RewriteRule search/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=search [QSA,L]

RewriteRule site-map/?$ /index.php?act=site-map [QSA,L]
RewriteRule site-map/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=site-map [QSA,L]
RewriteRule follow/?$ /index.php?act=follow [QSA,L]
RewriteRule follow/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=follow [QSA,L]
RewriteRule events/?$ /index.php?act=events [QSA,L]
RewriteRule events/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=events [QSA,L]
RewriteRule contact/?$ /index.php?act=contact [QSA,L]
RewriteRule contact/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=contact [QSA,L]

RewriteRule gallery/?$ /index.php?act=gallery [QSA,L]
RewriteRule gallery/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=gallery [QSA,L]
RewriteRule gallery/album/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?$ /index.php?act=gallery&module=album&id=$1&cpu=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule gallery/album/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=gallery&module=album&id=$1&cpu=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule page/?$ /index.php?act=page [QSA,L]
RewriteRule page/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=page [QSA,L]
RewriteRule page/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?$ /index.php?act=page&id=$1&cpu=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule page/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=page&id=$1&cpu=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule t/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?$ /index.php?act=teacher&cpu=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule t/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=teacher&cpu=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule t/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?$ /index.php?act=teacher&cpu=$1&id_p=$2&cpu_p=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule t/?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=teacher&cpu=$1&id_p=$2&cpu_p=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule news/?$ /index.php?act=news [QSA,L]
RewriteRule news/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=news [QSA,L]
RewriteRule news/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?$ /index.php?act=news&module=art&id=$1&cpu=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule news/?([0-9]+)?-?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)?/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=news&module=art&id=$1&cpu=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Как поправить их чтобы выполнялось перенаправления для /search, /search/ и /search/index.html на /index.php?act=search?
И конечно аналогично для всех остальных

Сейчас если дописать /search/index.html делается перенаправление на /index.php?act=main (Аналогично все остальные правила)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка уже в первой строке. Это правило сработает, если в `%{REQUEST_URI}` ***в любом месте*** встретится строка `index.html`. Поскольку оно стоит первым, оно чаще всего и сработает. Чтобы перенаправлять только адрес `/index.html`, правило должно быть записано следующим образом:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ /index.php?act=main [QSA,L]
```

Аналогичного вида ошибки и во всех остальных строках. Если нужно, чтобы `%{REQUEST_URI}` начинался с какой-либо строки, в начале условия перед этой строкой нужно поставить символ `^`:

```
RewriteRule ^main/?$ /index.php?act=main [QSA,L]
```

В общем, условие перенаправления - это (почти) обычное регулярное выражение.

Ещё одна ошибка в строках вида

```
RewriteRule main/?index.html?$ /index.php?act=main [QSA,L]
```

Это правило сработает не только для адреса `main/index.html`, но и для `mainindex.html`. Знак вопроса в регулярном выражении означает, что символ перед ним может встречаться ноль или один раз. Чтобы исправить, нужно записать так:

```
RewriteRule ^main/index.html?$ /index.php?act=main [QSA,L]
```